# Why virtual function call is faster than dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, performance, dynamic-cast, dispatch

I wrote a simple example, which estimates average time of calling virtual function, using base class interface and dynamic_cast and call of non-virtual function.
Here is it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <list>
#include <time.h>

#define CALL_COUNTER (3000)

__forceinline int someFunction()
{
  return 5;
}

struct Base
{
  virtual int virtualCall() = 0;
  virtual ~Base(){};
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  Derived(){};
  virtual ~Derived(){};
  virtual int virtualCall(){ return someFunction(); };
  int notVirtualCall(){ return someFunction(); };
};


struct Derived2 : public Base
{
  Derived2(){};
  virtual ~Derived2(){};
  virtual int virtualCall(){ return someFunction(); };
  int notVirtualCall(){ return someFunction(); };
};

typedef std::list<double> Timings;

Base* createObject(int i)
{
  if(i % 2 > 0)
    return new Derived(); 
  else 
    return new Derived2(); 
}

void callDynamiccast(Timings& stat)
{
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < CALL_COUNTER; ++i)
  {
    Base* ptr = createObject(i);

    clock_t startTime = clock();

    for(int j = 0; j < CALL_COUNTER; ++j)
    {
      Derived* x = (dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr));
      if(x) x->notVirtualCall();
    }

    clock_t endTime = clock();
    double callTime = (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    stat.push_back(callTime);

    delete ptr;
  }
}

void callVirtual(Timings& stat)
{
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < CALL_COUNTER; ++i)
  {
    Base* ptr = createObject(i);

    clock_t startTime = clock();

    for(int j = 0; j < CALL_COUNTER; ++j)
      ptr->virtualCall();


    clock_t endTime = clock();
    double callTime = (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    stat.push_back(callTime);

     delete ptr;
  }
}

int main()
{
  double averageTime = 0;
  Timings timings;


  timings.clear();
  callDynamiccast(timings);
  averageTime = (double) std::accumulate<Timings::iterator, double>(timings.begin(), timings.end(), 0);
  averageTime /= timings.size();
  std::cout << "time for callDynamiccast: " << averageTime << std::endl;

  timings.clear();
  callVirtual(timings);
  averageTime = (double) std::accumulate<Timings::iterator, double>(timings.begin(), timings.end(), 0);
  averageTime /= timings.size();
  std::cout << "time for callVirtual: " << averageTime << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It looks like callDynamiccast takes almost two times more.

`time for callDynamiccast: 0.000240333`

`time for callVirtual: 0.0001401`

Any ideas why does it?

EDITED: object creation is made in separete function now, so the compler does not know it real type. Almost the same result.

EDITED2: create two different types of a derived objects.

Comment: You probably need to run a lot more iterations that that to get a decent statistical measure.  Are you compiling at the highest optimisation setting?

Comment: I tryed with much more iterations, but the result is the same. All optimisations are off. I used MSVS2008.

Comment: Your test is invalid, because the compiler can easily optimize both the virtual call (into a nonvirtual call) and the dynamic_cast (into basically a noop), because it knows that `ptr` really points to a `Derived` object.

Comment: Write a function `Base* createBase()` which *randomly* returns `Base*` or `Derived*` and call it in each loop iteration.

Comment: Now the compiler cant know type because it duffers from one iteration to enother.

Comment: Ehm, the title says dynamic_cast is faster but the numbers show virtual is faster. Which is expected, I think.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, thats why I made lots of iterations and calculated avarage value.

Comment: @Dmitry - The resolution of `clock()` isn't that great. You probably need *a lot* more than 3000 calls to get a significant result. A difference of 0.0001 seconds isn't convincing!

Comment: @DmitryEskin: If you've turned optimisations off, then the results of the test mean absolutely nothing...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, why does it?

Comment: @DmitryEskin: Because it bears no resemblance to what the compiler is capable of doing when it performs optimisations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The virtual function call is similar to a function pointer, or if the compiler knows the type, static dispatch. This is constant time.

`dynamic_cast` is quite different -- it uses an implementation defined means to determine a type. It is not constant time, may traverse the class hierarchy (also consider multiple inheritance) and perform several lookups. An implementation may use string comparisons. Therefore, the complexity is higher in two dimensions. Real time systems often avoid/discourage `dynamic_cast` for these reasons.

More details are available [in this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf).

Comment: So, if I expand class hierarhy, dynamic_cast time will increse even more?

Comment: @Dmitry how it is implemented is defined by your implementation, but as a generalization yes, that's correct. the complexity of inheritance (number of bases and if multiple inheritance is used) is usually where the cost is introduced. if the classes are not related, your implementation may have a good optimization for that case. also note that there are a few edge cases which increase complexity -- `dynamic_cast` may fail where a singular base cannot be determined because two common bases exist. therefore, the entire hierarchy must be examined before returning.

Comment: Page 31 of the linked document has the pertinent details about a virtual call versus various dynamic_cast for several compilers (though I couldn't find where it told you which compilers were used).

Answer (score 10):

It should be noted that the *entire purpose* of virtual functions is to not have to cast down the inheritance graph. Virtual functions exist so that you can use a derived class instance as though it were a base class. So that more specialized implementations of functions can be called from code that originally called base class versions.

If virtual functions were slower than a safe cast to the derived-class + function call, then C++ compilers would simply implement virtual function calls that way.

So there's no reason to expect `dynamic_cast`+call to be faster.

Answer (score 5):

You are just measuring the cost of `dynamic_cast<>`.  It is implemented with RTTI, that's optional in any C++ compiler.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Language, Enable Run-Time Type Info setting.  Change it to No.

You'll now get an unsubtle reminder that `dynamic_cast<>` can no longer do the proper job.  Arbitrarily change it to `static_cast<>` to get drastically different results.  Key point here is that if you *know* that an upcast is always safe then `static_cast<>` buys you the performance you are looking for.  If you *don't know* for a fact that the upcast is safe then `dynamic_cast<>` keeps you out of trouble.  It is the kind of trouble that is maddingly hard to diagnose.  The common failure mode is heap corruption, you only get an immediate GPF if you are really lucky.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is, that you can call the virtual function on any instance that is derived from `Base`. The `notVirtualCall()` member does not exist within `Base`, and cannot be called without first determining the exact dynamic type of the object.

The consequence of this difference is, that the vtable of the base class includes a slot for `virtualCall()`, which contains a function pointer to the correct function to call. So, the virtual call simply chases the vtable pointer included as the first (invisible) member of all objects of type `Base`, loads the pointer from the slot corresponding to `virtualCall()`, and calls the function behind that pointer.

When you do a `dynamic_cast<>`, by contrast, the class `Base` does not know at compile time what other classes will eventually derive from it. Consequently, it cannot include information within its vtable that eases the resolution of the `dynamic_cast<>`. That is the information lack that makes a `dynamic_cast<>` more expensive to implement than a virtual function call. The `dynamic_cast<>` has to actually search through the inheritance tree of the actual object to check whether the destination type of the cast is found among its bases. That is work that the virtual call avoids.