# c++ - Inheritance and cast

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm writing a 2d game and want to make it right from the beginning. I'm not entirely sure how to solve multiple inheritance and casting.

Lets say for instance that i have a game world. I create a class called **Environment** which all the objects will inherit.

Now if i create another class called Brick and Ground, this two classes are going to inherit the functions from environment. Now lets say i want to be able to explode the Brick upon contact, but the ground class won't ever use it, so it would be a waste to create a function like that in the environment class and make it virtual.

So i though, maybe if i cast the environment object back to the derived class and call its functions from there: (Only a example below to demonstrate the though process)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

class Environment
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int damage;
public:
    Environment(std::string _name)
    {
        this->name = _name;
    }

    virtual std::string GetType() = 0;

    std::string GetName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        std::cout << this->name << ": Spawning object..." << std::endl;
    }

    int GetHealth()
    {
        return this->health;
    }

    void TakeDamage(int _damage)
    {
        this->health-=_damage;
    }

    virtual void Update() = 0;
    virtual void Render() = 0;
    virtual ~Environment(){}
};

class Ground : public Environment
{
private:

public:
    Ground(std::string _name) : Environment(_name)
    {

    }

    std::string GetType()
    {
        return "Ground";
    }

    void Update()
    {
        std::cout << "Updating: " << this->name << std::endl;
    }

    void Render()
    {

    }

};

class Brick : public Environment
{
private:

public:
    Brick(std::string _name) : Environment(_name)
    {
        this->name = "Brick Ansikte";
        this->health = 100;
    }

    std::string GetType()
    {
        return "Brick";
    }

    void Update()
    {
        std::cout << "Updating: " << this->name << std::endl;
    }

    void Render()
    {

    }

    void Explode()
    {
        std::cout << "Exploding BRICK" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Environment*> listEnvironment;
    listEnvironment.push_back(new Ground("Ground fool"));
    listEnvironment.push_back(new Brick("Ground tun"));

    for(auto& env : listEnvironment)
    {
        std::cout << "HP: " << env->GetHealth() << std::endl; 
        env->Spawn();
        env->Update();
        if (env->GetType() == "Brick")
        {
            std::cout << "BRICK TYPE WAS FOUND, DYNAMIC CAST" << std::endl;
            static_cast<Brick*>(env)->Explode();

        }

        delete env;
    }
    listEnvironment.empty();


    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Is this solution good or bad? Or should i create yet another base helper class that holds all the different type of actions that can occur in the game? Like explode, bounce etc etc?

Best regards
nilo

Comment: Instead of `env->GetType()=="Brick"`, why not use `Brick* br = dynamic_cast<Brick*>(env); if (env != nullptr)`? Safer, clearer, and bypasses the issue.

Comment: Well the code above is only a prototype which is badly written to demonstrate the though process behind the project. But you are right, i wrote dynamic cast but used static cast anyways in the example :) Cheers

Comment: Why do you think it's a "waste" to add an `Explode` function to `Environment`? It makes the code a lot cleaner. You can have the default implementation do nothing, and let those objects capable of exploding override it with the proper behavior.

Comment: Well this is a 2d game, so the default implementation does take care of alot of things to be honest. Explosion is only 1 out of maybe 20-30 other functions that might be implemented so putting everything in Environment doesnt seem like a good idea. I mean if i put a new object called grass, with its own textures and stuff, that basically only needs to exist in the world, whats the point of having 30-40 other functions available that i will never use?

Comment: My apologies, but I've been designing Enterprise systems for years...this is a big mistake.  I see no consistencies among the example you gave.  Think about your system first, a game world has players, walls, floors, etc.  So if you want things that explode create an appropriate base class type (I know `Environment`) but you can do all of it without ever casting.  Just remember, if you cast too many times you should be rethinking your design.

Comment: Why would you want to inherit `Brick` from `Environment`? What `Environment` represent? Anyway, wanting to check types at run time smells like trouble.

Comment: thank you guys, I will play around with it a little bit and post some code in a couple of hours. Best regards nilo

Comment: Well i have another question here. Lets say for instance that i only have access to a void* that needs to be cast to the origin class when the contact-callback function is called. Is it smarter to use enum to detect the type and than cast it back to the class or should i use dynamic_cast? Seems like the first solution is better otherwise i have to write one line for every single class and using typeid only returns the base class. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

1. Use `dynamic_cast`:

   ```
   if (Brick* brick = dynamic_cast<Brick*>(env))
   {
       std::cout << "BRICK TYPE WAS FOUND, DYNAMIC CAST" << std::endl;
       brick->explode();
   }
   ```
2. Add another method to `Environment` named something like `MaybeExplode` (that's actually a really bad name, but I can't really think of something better):

   ```
   virtual void MaybeExplode() {}
   ```

   Now, override it in `Brick`:

   ```
   void MaybeExplode()
   {
       std::cout << "Exploding BRICK" << std::endl;
   }
   ```

   Then unconditionally call `MaybeExplode` in your `for` loop:

   ```
   ...
   env->Spawn();
   env->Update();
   env->MaybeExplode();

   delete env;
   ```

   This is *not* wasteful. It's really how OO design is. The person asking for an explosion doesn't know *what* `env` is.

   Also, `dynamic_cast` is actually [slower than a virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959315/why-virtual-function-call-is-faster-than-dynamic-cast), so, if anything, your current version is *more* wasteful.

Comment: He doesn't actually have a `dynamic_cast`, he's implemented his own version which is even slower still.

Comment: @MooingDuck I though he was saying (to paraphrase) *I used dynamic_cast in the real version*, not *I wrote my own custom dynamic_cast*.