# using dynamic cast to return different values for variable inside derived class

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Trying to find a way to get my dynamic cast to work, but I keep getting runtime errors. It jumps to the else statement block value when printed out (when it should be an if block value, but is not even used when I invoke it inside the derived class. So it's displaying the wrong value and also not using it at all in the calculation. Why is this? Thanks for the help.

```
class Package
{
protected:
    string name_and_address = "?";

    double cost = 0.0;
    double discount = 0.0;
    double discount_rate = 0.0;

    bool overnight_delivery = false;
    bool insured = false;

    string package_contents = "?";

    double shipcost = 0.0;

public:
    Package() {};
    ~Package() {};

protected:
    virtual double calculate_cost() = 0;

    class Video_Games {}; //defined the classes
    class Genius_Phone {};
    class Sausage {};
    class Albums {};

    // here I'm trying to change "shipcost" inside each of the derived classes
    // to their respective and appropriate dollar values.
    // However, I am getting a runtime error wherein it will jump DIRECTLY
    // to the else statement 50.00 value for Video_Games
    // and not even calculate the value as 50.00. SO it's doubly useless.
    // It just skips to the else value and doesn't even factor
    // that into the Video_Games calculation when I try to test it. 
    virtual double shipping_cost() {
        if (dynamic_cast<Video_Games*>(this)) 
            return 4.99;
        else if (dynamic_cast<Genius_Phone*>(this))
            return 25.00;
        else if (dynamic_cast<Sausage*>(this))
            return 9.00;
        else
        {
            // should be assigned to class Albums,
            // but is somehow being triggered by class Video_Games.
            // Not sure why this is. 
            return 50.00; 
        }
    }
};

class Video_Games :public Package
{
private:
    int num_games = 0;

public:
    Video_Games(string location, int number_of_games, bool express, bool insurance)
    {
        num_games = number_of_games;
        name_and_address = location;
        overnight_delivery = express;
        insured = insurance;

        package_contents = to_string(num_games) + " Video Game(s)";

        cost = calculate_cost();
        discount = calculate_discount();
        shipcost = shipping_cost();
    }

    ~Video_Games() {};

protected:

    double calculate_cost()
    {
        cost = num_games * 19.99;
        // this is where the magic should happen.
        // shipcost here should be 4.99, but instead it's not even being used here.
        // In fact - it's empty. I'm not sure why shipcost
        // when set equal shipping_cost() is not returning that appropriate value.
        // Very baffling. 
        if (overnight_delivery) { cost += shipcost; } 
        if (insured) { cost *= 1.06; }

        return cost;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's because you are doing it wrong. You should look at this page on how to use it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: It's funny you linked that page. I tried doing it that way, and I got the same end result. Maybe you could show me how to factor this code in that way?

Comment: Unrelated to the question - but why aren't you using some kind of polymorphic `GetShippingCost()` function? It would be way more readable and will prevent you from having this ugly conditionals/`dynamic_cast` mixture.

Comment: I'm trying to print out the shipping cost inside superclass Package and have it be unique for each type of shipping price without having to manually insert the shipping price each time

Comment: Superclass, that knows something about derived classes- isn't a good example of inheritance.

Comment: Since "shipping_cost" is a virtual function you should just add override functions in each derived class and thus avoid the dynamic_cast. In general you should try to find ways to avoid dynamic_cast as it is unsafe and have a high runtime cost.

Comment: Why using `dynamic_cast` at all? What you want there is [Strategy design pattern](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DesignPatterns/strategy.php)

Comment: I'm getting a lot of "don't use dynamic_cast" but the thing is, I was able to get to this point from someone with 300K + reputation who told me that accomplishing this with dynamic casting was (one of the ways) to go.

Comment: Not a very good way to go though. This defeats the whole point of virtual functions.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @N.Gerontidis: What is the difference in runtime cost between `dynamic_cast` and virtual function dispatch?

Comment: @polymorphism: It's certainly valid and possible, it's just not how we generally choose to design such programs. You're putting information about how derived classes should behave, into the base class. That's generally a big no-no in OOP. It also makes it more difficult and error-prone to add new cases. Virtual dispatch was invented for the sole purpose of doing this properly, and that's why people are suggesting you use that instead. Which 300k+ user suggested `dynamic_cast` for this task? We ought to set him or her straight!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be honest I have not performed tests and benchmarkings on this, I just know the theory. But in case you are interested, I have found a nicely detailed answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959315/why-virtual-function-call-is-faster-than-dynamic-cast

Answer (score 5):

The problem is how you've defined the other classes:

```
class Package
{
    class Video_Games {}; //defined the classes
    class Genius_Phone {};
    class Sausage {};
    class Albums {};
```

These are nested types, inside `Package`. You've defined a class `Package::Video_Games` which has no base classes and no members. The `dynamic_cast` expressions use *these* types, which are not derived from `Package`:

```
        if (dynamic_cast<Video_Games*>(this)) 
            return 4.99;
```

Name lookup within the `Package::shipping_cost()` function finds the `Package::Video_Games` type, which is the empty class with no base classes or members. The object is never that type, because `Package::Video_Games` isn't derived from `Package` so the `this` pointer of type `Package*` can't point to an object of type `Package::Video_Games`.

Later you define new types with the same names, that *are* derived from `Package`:

```
class Video_Games :public Package
{
```

But this is a new type. `Video_Games` is not the same type as `Package::Video_Games`. When you define a derived package object it will use this type, not the one that the cast uses. So your casts will never succeed.

You need to remove the definitions of the nested types inside `Package` and move the body of your `Package::shipping_cost()` function outside the class, after all the other types have been defined (so the compiler has seen the definitions of those other types and knows they are derived from `Package`).

```
class Package
{
  virtual double shipping_cost();
  // ...
};

class Video_Games : public Package
{
  // ...
};

// Now you can define the virtual function:
double Package::shipping_cost()
{
  if (dynamic_cast<Video_Games*>(this))
    // ...
}
```

(But as the comments say, this is a really bad way to define a polymorphic interface -- it defeats the whole purpose of virtual functions.)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I'm slowly digesting your work and it's starting to make sense. However, I'm finding trouble with the `shipcost` variable as it says it's undefined now. Not sure why. I cast `shipcost=shipping_cost()` inside the Video_Games derived class, but it's still gnawing at my foot telling me it's not defined even though I declared it as you said inside class Package.

Comment: Okay, I'm playing whack-a-mole with this program right now...I got it to compile nicely, and it displays the shipping cost _exactly_ how I wanted. 

However, now the derived Video_Games class is giving me **the shipping cost of 50.00 calculated with the total, yet it displays 4.99 as the shipcost, however (and that is correct and what it should be, not the 50.00 which it is using implicitly in the calculations)**....so now my problem has been flipped on its head. Before I was getting the 50.00 displayed as the shipping cost and the 4.99 calculated. My head is now officially spinning.

Comment: In fact, per your method all of the calculations are done with the 50.00 valuation of shipping cost while all of the displayed shipcost is accurate per derived class.

Comment: You're calling `calculate_cost()` before you've done `shipcost = shipping_cost();` which means it uses the default value of `shipcost`, which is `0.0`. Learn to use a debugger, or just add code to print values to standard output during the calculations, so you can see what is going on with your code. Understand it step by step instead of trying to write hundreds of lines that don't work and then playing whack-a-mole.

Comment: Alternatively I was thinking I could just stick the appropriate "Your shipping cost is X" string into each if-statement inside the protected calculate_cost within each derived class. I think that's really easy and but it won't be nice and clean and inside my package-class as an output. It'll just be spit out anywhere at the beginning of my program.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, given your username, you're missing out on using polymorphism to provide the correct implementation.  Instead of switching on type, you can call the virtual method, and that will pick up the correct version:

```
class Package {
public:
    virtual ~Package();
    virtual double shipping_cost() const;
};
class Video_Games : public Package {
public:
    double shipping_cost() const override;
};
class Genius_Phone : public Package {
public:
    double shipping_cost() const override;
};
class Sausage : public Package {
public:
    double shipping_cost() const override;
};

Package::~Package() {}

double Package::shipping_cost() const
{
    // Default implementation - may be overridden in subclasses
    return 50.00;
}

double Video_Games::shipping_cost() const
{
    return 4.99;
}

double Genius_Phone::shipping_cost() const
{
    return 25.99;
}

double Sausage::shipping_cost() const
{
    return 9.00;
}
```

I should also warn that using floating-point types for monetary values will lead you into trouble - a search of Stack Overflow should find answers explaining why.

Comment: You miss the inheritance.

Comment: Quite right - thanks to @Lightness for fixing on my behalf.

Comment: The good news is that I did declare the methods `override` so that the compiler would tell you about the mistake.  :-)

Comment: Still getting a runtime error where the shipcost is not being passed into the calculation portion of the subclass. Not sure why. Same as Jonathan's problem. It shows me that it knows what the subclass version of variable is, then proceeds to use 0.00 instead for the calculation. I think there's a barrier of some sort between the display of the shipcost and the ability of it to being changed and manipulated inside the calculation.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem as Jonathan's. I'm going to go ahead and make a new question. Thanks everyone for helping out.

Comment: I did it. It worked. Finally. I was able to also in the process do the same thing for the insurance rate. It was amazing. I feel like I'm taking drugs right now I'm so stoked. u n l i m i t e d p o w e r .